# TeX capacity exceeded using beamer and minted

Tags: beamer, minted

I am working on a code-heavy `beamer` and I want to spice the presentation up a bit with `minted` syntax highlighting. I have the following frame:

```
\section{WebAssembly}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \frametitle{A Title}
    \framesubtitle{A Primer}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item It's structured
    \end{itemize}
    \begin{minted}{fsharp}
    let x = 5
    \end{minted}
\end{frame}
```

Which shouldn't be a problem as far as I can Google; however I am seeing a problem I've never encountered before:

```
:<+ _minted-template/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle.tex
(./_minted-template/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle)
:<-
:<+ _minted-template/default.pygstyle.tex
(./_minted-template/default.pygstyle)
:<-
:<+ _minted-template/95968A064C521BB75BD855349274DBE9FD7A398216DC386A05A21C5506
BB3C28.pygtex.tex

(./_minted-template/95968A064C521BB75BD855349274DBE9FD7A398216DC386A05A21C5506B
B3C28.pygtex)
:<-
)
:<-
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
\par ->



l.116 \end{frame}
```

Why does this happen? I don't imagine that the code by itself would hit a memory limit(it's a one-liner) and I get the same errors using different languages and using `\inputminted` instead. I also included a [Preamble](https://pastebin.com/XNpesU3g) which might help.

I know people have successfully used `minted` in `beamer`, and I can't really switch to Listings (`fsharp` isn't the primary language). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please provide an example that shows the error, if I put `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}` before your fragment and `\end{document}` after it, it runs without error.

Comment: please don't link to external sites, especially with minted that requires shell-escape. make a small self contained document with just teh minimal number of packages required to show th eproblem and add it as a code block in the question

Comment: Puzzling together the preamble and your code fragment, it still compiles fine. This question really needs a minimal working example which reproduces the problem